# Images from S3 not loading, 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I have a simple app that should show an image hosted on S3. Image loads fine in the browser:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mlsgrid/images/a54e5e4c-e205-4b98-9ee7-4746b75d0a61.jpg

However when embeded in html  tag, I get 403 forbidden:

[image]

I tried adding CORS but still won't work. What do I need to do to be able to show this image?

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
            });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you think it's CORS? If it is, the console tab would show an error. E.g. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: REASON`.

Comment: You can add CORS permissions to the S3 bucket, see: [Using cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html)

Comment: images aren't generally blocked by CORS.

Comment: notice the type is listed as xml, not an image. you might have to correct the object metadata in s3.

Comment: Is image a base64 string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did fix it on the front end like this:

```
           <meta name="referrer" content="same-origin" />
            <img
                alt={imageList[activeStep]?.label || 'Image not found'}
                className={classes.img}
```